# Why do I get an Invalid scope error when calling the Pre-Create App User Smooch api

Tags: smooch

I'm POSTing to the Pre-Create App User endpoint https://api.smooch.io/v1.1/apps/{appId}/appusers for smooch, using the appUser as the scope in my JWT, but I get this response:
{"error":{"code":"forbidden","description":"Invalid scope"}}

I tried the exact same JWT doing a GET to       /v1.1/apps/{appId}/appusers/{userId} and that succeeded.

I did also try the app scope in case that was required for the create but not the get, but that also failed.
Is there some other scope I should be using?

Comment: `app` or `account` scope are both valid for the pre-create user API, `appUser` scope is not allowed. Can you post the error you get when using `app` scope?

Comment: My error for the app scope was:
{"code":"invalid_auth","description":"Invalid JWT body. Cannot use userId param with app scope"}
Which I now understand was caused by leaving the userId claim in the JWT.
So using the app scope and removing the userId claim fixed my issue.